# Count list of object which value is not null

Tags: dart

How can I count a objects in a list which value is not null? I've got an list of objects and I need to count objects which value is not null. In this example count objects in value1 where age in not null

```
var list = {'value1':[{'name': 'name1', 'age': null}, 
                      {'name': 'name2', 'age': 30},
                      {'name': 'name3', 'age': 10}], 
            'value2':[{'name': 'name11', 'age': 40}, 
                      {'name': 'name12', 'age': null},
                      {'name': 'name13', 'age': 10}]};
}
```

so `print(list['value1']...)` should return 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where` to filter your input and hereafter use `length` to count the number of elements which fulfill your filter:

```
void main() {
  var list = {
    'value1': [
      {'name': 'name1', 'age': null},
      {'name': 'name2', 'age': 30},
      {'name': 'name3', 'age': 10}
    ],
    'value2': [
      {'name': 'name11', 'age': 40},
      {'name': 'name12', 'age': null},
      {'name': 'name13', 'age': 10}
    ]
  };

  print(list['value1'].where((object) => object['age'] != null).length); // 2
}
```

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi sorry... this is much better answer